# How to ignore a test in C# when CurrentEnv is Prod

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, c#, nunit

I have created a ProdIgnoreAttribute which extends from `IgnoreAttribute`.
And I have assigned this attribute to certain tests which I want to run in DEV/QA but not in PROD.

> ApplyToTest(Test test) method is not being called in this case. How to resolve this?

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class ProdIgnoreAttribute : IgnoreAttribute
{
    private string IgnoreReason { get; }

    public ProdIgnoreAttribute(string reason) : base(reason) 
    {
        IgnoreReason = reason;
    }

    public new void ApplyToTest(Test test)
    {
        if (test.RunState == RunState.NotRunnable)
            return;

        if (StaticInfoHelper.VrCurrentEnv == (int)RunEnv.DEMO)
        {
            test.RunState = RunState.Ignored;
            test.Properties.Set("_SKIPREASON", (object)IgnoreReason);
        }
        else
        {
            base.ApplyToTest(test);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple of thoughts... You can use category instead.  Tests can be run by category.  Look into the TestSettings file.  I don't know of a way to inject an attributeType at run time into a class based on CurrentEnv.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have modified the code in my question. But facing another problem. Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would go another way.

1. Set test categories for the given tests (e.g. "QA", "DEV", "PROD")
2. Create a CI job for NUnit test execution for given category on a specific environment. 1 category - 1 job.
3. If needed - create a master job which will trigger the child (environment-specific jobs) and this will allow you execute the tests against your environments at once.

I think the code itself should be environment agnostic and condition logic depending on environment variables will reduce the readability and increase maintenance effort.
Creating the jobs on the CI is not a silver bullet as well, but there is always a some point of a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

The reason ApplyToTest is not called is because it is declared as new.
new is not the same as override.

You should instead inherit from : NUnitAttribute, IApplyToTest

Then it will work.